# Getting Error when using third party url

Tags: apex, community, force.com, apexrest

I am using Salesforce.com platform. I am getting error when i am calling Rest API.
Like this:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('myurl');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug('RESPONSE BODY'+ res.getBody());
```

In response I am getting following ERROR:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

My URL already CA certified. Should I do for upload this? or any solutions?

Comment: What is your endpoint. Is it http or https? This error comes in https based communication only. If it is https then it needs to have a certificate from CA to which salesforce trusts.
Salesforce trusted CAs can be found here : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#addtrustclass1ca

Comment: yes endpoint is https. my url is already CA certified but when tried to use that https url in salesforce. it is giving me error

Comment: IMO, you will have to also send CA Certificate along with the request. Check setClientCertificateName attribute for HTTP Request

Comment: the issue also can occur if your endpoint is certified by CA but the root certificate is not know by Salesforce. Check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68189/error-doing-callout-to-a-site-with-godaddy-certificate